# Read a Sequence value after insert with a trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sequence, auto-increment

I'm developing a small app in Pro*C, but I have a question with one of the main features.

I have an auto increment trigger for the identifier of each table, so before the row gets inserted into the table, the trigger sets the id of the row.

The problem here is that I want to retrieve the value of the sequence after an isert (to get the id of the row inserted), but what happens when two transactions are trying to insert a a row? If I use the read-commited level and I commit the transaction after inserting the row and retrieve it's value can cause any problems? What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: How are you currently getting the value? By querying for `currval` (in the same session, even if committed), with the `returning` clause, or something else?

Comment: I'm getting the value after the insert statement by querying `currval`

Comment: OK, and the two transactions doing inserts are in different sessions? They're independent, `currval` is local to the session. Are you actually having a problem or just figuring out if what you're doing is safe?

Comment: The inserts will be on different sessions, I was just figuring it out what is the safe way to do that. But as you say, if the values are independent for each session, I will not have any problem, right?

Comment: `currval` is perfectly safe for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe for two sessions to independently insert rows and refer to `currval`, as it's local to the session.

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns002.htm) doesn't quiet state that clearly:

> ... Any reference to CURRVAL always returns the current value of the sequence, which is the value returned by the last reference to NEXTVAL.
>
> Before you use CURRVAL for a sequence in your session, you must first initialize the sequence with NEXTVAL.

Taken together they show it's safe, but the first part of that doesn't really make it clear that it's the last reference to `NEXTVAL` *in the current session*. It does, however, say:

> A sequence can be accessed by many users concurrently with no waiting or locking.

However, you don't need to do a query to get the ID, you can use [the `returning into` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm#i2122356)

```
insert into your_table (col1, ...) values (:val1, ...)
returning id into :id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I will use the `returning` clause here. I don't know I can use it with Pro*C.